# ErrorException (E_ERROR)Trying to get property 'title' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) Trying to get property 'title' of non-object
>   (View:
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\practise\freecode\resources\views\profiles\index.blade.php)

Previous exceptions

> Trying to get property 'title' of non-object (0)

```
            <div class="d-flex">
                <div ><strong>{{ $user->posts->count() }}</strong> posts</div>
                <div class="pl-5"><strong>23k</strong> followers</div>
                <div class="pl-5"><strong>435</strong> following</div>
            </div>
            <div class="pt-4 font-weight-bold" ><strong>{{ $user->profile->title }}</strong></div>
            <div>{{ $user->profile->description }}</div>
            <div><a href="#">{{ $user->profile->url ??'N/A' }}</a></div>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="row pt-5">
    @foreach($user->posts as $post)
    <div class="col-4" >
        <img src="/storage/{{ $post->image }}" class="w-100"> 
    </div>
    @endforeach
```

After posting showing this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you clearly read the errors message, it says you are trying to access title on a null object.This means that the following relation is null.

```
 $user->profile // returns null
```

A quick way of error handling this, is using the null coalescing operator. This checks if the first statement at any point returns null, if not it returns the first statement. Else it have a fallback to the second statement.

```
{{ $user->profile->title ?? 'user not found'; }}
```

Comment: After using this code {{ $user->profile->title ?? 'user not found;' }}.
There are shown "user not found;' and shown images.

Comment: Did it help or is it not as intended?

Answer (score 0):

use array instead of object

```
{{ $user->profile['title'] }}
```

Answer (score 0):

To quickly fix it do this raplace

```
     $user->profile->title
```

by

```
    {{ $user->profile? $user->profile->title:"" }}
```

Comment: you have to vote the best answer (the anwser which help you), so that the question will be close and other user who have the same problem should use this answer